# Tweepy: Get screen_name from search result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

I'm trying to get screen_names from a Tweepy search that iterates through a list of possible search values.

```
import tweepy
positive = 'yes', 'yep', 'yepp'

yes = 0
for vote in positive:
    print(vote)
    voteYes = api.search(q='{} #waterbecky'.format(vote))
    for tweet in voteYes:
        #extract screen_name here and increase yes by 1
```

My trouble is figuring out the code to pull screennames from that list of searches. I've searched all over to find an answer, but everything I find involves knowing each tweet's ID value first, then getting the screen_name from that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon the answer after taking a look at the JSON tweepy returns from a search.

```
for votes in positive:
    votesPos = api.search(q='#waterbecky {}'.format(votes))
    for content in votePos:
        print(content.author._json['screen_name'])
```